# Header misbehave on longer title

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have problem with misbehaving header:
[image: screenshot]

Code looks like this:

```
<div class="row row-grid">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <h2 class="pull-right"><span class="label label-warning">1</span></h2>
            <h3 class="pull-left shadow">         
               Piotrek z Bagien
               <br>
               <span><h4 class="gray shadow">Pinta</h4></span>
                <span><h6 class="gray shadow">India Pale Ale (Poland)</h6></span>              
            </h3>   
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="" id="sub-row">     
            <span class="col-sm-6 white-text">7 zł / 9 zł / 12 zł</span>
            <span class="col-sm-6 white-text">5.2%/90 IBU</span>
        </div>
     </div>

     <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <h2 class="pull-right"><span class="label label-warning">1</span></h2>
            <h3 class="pull-left shadow">         
               Piotrek z Bagien India Pale Ale
               <br>
               <span><h4 class="gray shadow">Pinta</h4></span>
                <span><h6 class="gray shadow">India Pale Ale (Poland)</h6></span>              
            </h3>   
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="" id="sub-row">     
            <span class="col-sm-6 white-text">7 zł / 9 zł / 12 zł</span>
            <span class="col-sm-6 white-text">5.2%/90 IBU</span>
        </div>
     </div>


  </div>
```

What I want to achieve is to concat String with "..." if too long or other elegant solution that won't destroy whole layout.

edit: Almost there thanks to answer. Now it looks like this:
[image]
and I have two questions:

- why left side of the concatenated text lost it's shadow?
- how to make it work when screen gets smaller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make trailing dots with something like this:

HTML

```
<div class="toolong">
    this text is just too loooooooooooooooooooooooooong
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 .toolong {
    width: 300px;
    overflow:hidden; 
    white-space:nowrap; 
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jguaxbsg/

Comment: Almost there. Updated my question.

Comment: Is there any possibility to adapt width to element's actual width after resize?

Comment: It led me to another problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33945653/concatenating-text-within-fluid-container