# Concatenating text within fluid container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

It's a problem that derived originally from that one: [Header misbehave on longer title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33938161/header-misbehave-on-longer-title)

I'm using now:

```
    .toolong {
        width: 230px;
        overflow:hidden; 
        white-space:nowrap; 
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }
```

with `@media (min-max width etc.)` and I want it to make width adapt to actual width of the container, not the screen width. Why is that? Because under, let's say, 768px I have stacked all the columns and container gets quite long with lot of unused space:
[image]

How to get this one right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply set:

```
width: 100%;
```

See the modified Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/blocknotes/jguaxbsg/2/

If there is enough space on the window you can see the whole sentence, if you restrict the window the ellipsis appear to cut the string.

Comment: I put 80% so it'd keep on one line. Works now - thanks!